# Soundpool with loop not working properly

Tags: android, loops, soundpool

I have a sound clip play while I am displaying some numbers, then want it to stop.  Then I want to repeat the process.

init stuff:

```
    private SoundPool soundPool;
    private int soundRoll;
    boolean soundloaded = false;
    this.setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    soundPool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new OnLoadCompleteListener() {
      @Override
      public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
            soundloaded = true;
      }
    });
    soundRoll = soundPool.load(this, R.raw.roll, 1);
```

Thread Call:

```
    public void update() {
    .......
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
         int streamID = 0;
         streamID = soundPool.play(soundRoll, volume, volume, 1, -1, 1);
         ... loop to animate text....
         soundPool.stop(streamID);
         }
    }).start();
    }
```

This works fine every other time.
so the first time it plays and stops at the right time.
second time I hear nothing
but then it works the third time

If I take out the looping, then it works.

Any help would be appretiated

Comment: try change from streamID = soundPool.play(soundRoll, volume, volume, 1, -1, 1); to  streamID = soundPool.play(soundRoll, volume, volume, 1, 1, 1); remove -1 n check it

Comment: Post your code for thread..

Answer (score 0):

Seems that if I switch to an OGG file from an MP3, the bug goes away